# How to make width of table dynamic depending upon table contents and at the same time it should have min-width of 25em

Tags: html, css

I have style in that I have used table layout: fixed to make the width dynamic but if there is only two word or three word content in the table than I don't want it to shrink drastically. I want to set minimum width of 25 em . I tried using min-width but it doesn't work.plz help

Comment: Add some code to your post so we can see what you have tried so far. You could try adding !important to the min-width attribute to force it.

Comment: I tried using important but it doesn't work actually my table has two sections of 25em each and between two sections there is a middle section of cellspqcing 4 in the middle section there are buttons to send values between the two sections. Now what I want to do is that I want to make the two sections dynamic so I used width:auto but at the same time I want to set minimum width of 25em or 400 px whatever.

Comment: The problem is the style in which width is defined is in extra html of an element and I cannot use div and expressions are also not working there

Comment: I tried using expression , important declaration, it just doesn't work on IE

Comment: How about you actually post some code and we can see what you have tried already.